# after adding uitableview to uiview didselectrowatindexpath not called ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have created a custom tableview **displayCustomUnitTableView** and a custom UIView **displayView** and adding **displayCustomUnitTableView** to **displayView**. But i am not able to select any row in the tableView i.e., **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** is not called.

I am using the following code:

```
displayCustomUnitTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(52.0, 110.0, 180.0, 110.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
displayCustomUnitTableView.delegate = self;
displayCustomUnitTableView.dataSource = self;
displayCustomUnitTableView.tag = 2;
displayCustomUnitTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
displayCustomUnitTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
displayCustomUnitTableView.rowHeight = 30.f;
[displayCustomUnitTableView setBackgroundColor:[ContentViewController colorFromHexString:@"#BCC9D1"]];
[displayCustomUnitTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
[displayCustomUnitTableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
[displayView addSubview:displayCustomUnitTableView];
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  if(tableView.tag == 1)
  {   
    cell.textLabel.text = [storeUnitList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
  else if(tableView.tag == 2)
  {
    cell.textLabel.text = [storeCustomUnitList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
   return cell;
 }
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if(tableView.tag == 1)
 {
    unitString = [storeUnitList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 else if(tableView.tag == 2)
 {
    unitString = [storeCustomUnitList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show where you have implemented the delegates ?

Comment: Please check i edited my post

Comment: Your code working perfectly in my xcode project. didSelectRowAtIndexPath is working here. only required numberOfRowsInSection delegate of TableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any UIGestures on the superviews. In that case UITableView will be not getting the touches.

If you have any, handle it using :

`- gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
Regiseter a cell class with tabel

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    displayCustomUnitTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(52.0, 110.0, 180.0, 110.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
displayCustomUnitTableView.delegate = self;
displayCustomUnitTableView.dataSource = self;
displayCustomUnitTableView.tag = 2;
displayCustomUnitTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
displayCustomUnitTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
displayCustomUnitTableView.rowHeight = 30.f;
[displayCustomUnitTableView setBackgroundColor:[ContentViewController colorFromHexString:@"#BCC9D1"]];
[displayCustomUnitTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
[displayCustomUnitTableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
[displayView addSubview:displayCustomUnitTableView];

    [displayCustomUnitTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

}

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{return 1;}



    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"i" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        /*

         Write code

         */
         cell.textLabel.text= @"hello";


        return cell;

    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSLog(@"Click");
    }
```

Comment: still its not getting called

Comment: are you sure you register cell class with tabel

Comment: [displayCustomUnitTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];